# Bug in reading PMG P5 file

Tags: c, struct

I have tried very hard and this is my best shot at tring to read a pmg P5 file . But during runtime , it seems that I am not being able to properly scan the P5  file during reading . Please help me find out the bug in my code .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct image{
    int nrow;
    int ncol;
    char s[10];
    int max;
    int **matrix;
};

int **mem_alloc(int,int);
void mem_dealloc(int **,int);
struct image *read_pgm(const char *,struct image *);
void write_pgm(const char *,const struct image *);

int main(){
    struct image *img;
    img=NULL;
    img=read_pgm("C:/MinGW/bin/image_P5.pgm",img);
    write_pgm("C:/MinGW/bin/write_P5.pgm",img);
    mem_dealloc((*img).matrix,(*img).nrow);
    printf("\nDone !\n");
    return 0;
}
int **mem_alloc(int nrow,int ncol){
    int **q;    
    int i,j;
    q=(int **)malloc(nrow*sizeof(int *));
    if(q==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"\nMemory allocation failure .\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(i=0;i<ncol;i++){
        q[i]=(int *)malloc(ncol*sizeof(int));
        if(q[i]==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr,"\nMemory allocation failure .\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}

void mem_dealloc(int **q,int nrow){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<nrow;i++){
        free(q[i]);
    }
    free(q);
}

struct image *read_pgm(const char *filename,struct image *img){
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen(filename,"rb"))!=NULL){
        int i,j;
        unsigned char *r;
        printf("56");
        fscanf(fp,"%s",(*img).s);
        printf("59");
        fscanf(fp,"%d%d%d",&((*img).ncol),&((*img).nrow),&((*img).max));
        printf("%s\n%d %d\n%d",(*img).s,(*img).ncol,(*img).nrow,(*img).max);
        r=(unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*((*img).ncol));
        (*img).matrix=mem_alloc((*img).nrow,(*img).ncol);

        for(i=0;i<(*img).nrow;i++){
            if(!(fread(r,sizeof(unsigned char),(*img).ncol,fp)==(*img).ncol)){
                fprintf(stderr,"\nDid not read line %d properly !.\n",i+1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            else{
                for(j=0;j<(*img).ncol;j++){
                    ((*img).matrix)[i][j]=((int)r[j] > 127)?(*img).max:0;
                }
            }
        }
        free(r);
        fclose(fp);
        return img;
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr,"\nCould not open file :\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

}

void write_pgm(const char *filename,const struct image *img){
    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen(filename,"wb"))!=NULL){
        int i,j;
        unsigned char *w;
        fprintf(fp,"%s\n%d %d\n%d\n",(*img).s,(*img).ncol,(*img).nrow,(*img).max);

        w=(unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)*((*img).ncol));

        for(i=0;i<(*img).nrow;i++){
            for(j=0;j<(*img).ncol;j++){
                w[j]=(unsigned char)((*img).matrix)[i][j];
            }
            if(fwrite(w,sizeof(unsigned char),(*img).ncol,fp)!=(*img).ncol){
                fprintf(stderr,"\nDid not read line %d properly .\n",i+1);
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
        }
        free(w);
        fclose(fp);
    }
    else{
        fprintf(stderr,"\nCould not open file %s",filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
```

**Okay , so I fixed it ! [final](http://codepad.org/ONbHw8ln) . There were some silly errors here and there that are hopefully gone now !**

Comment: [Here is the code][1]    


  [1]: https://ideone.com/4J01zr

Comment: Post the code as text in the question instead of link.

Comment: You pass a NULL pointer to `read_pgm()`.

Comment: Side note: when using pointers, you should use the `->` operator. For example, `(*img).s` should be written as `img->s`.

Comment: I have tried all possiblities . Even removing img=NULL  does not work.

Comment: When you initialize `img` to NULL, and then pass it in to `read_pgm`.  Then `read_pgm` dereferences `img` in the call to `fscanf`.  This will crash.  You need to create a valid image object and set `img` to point to it so that `read_img` has something to write data into.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at all the code, but the main error I see is you pass a NULL pointer to `read_pgm()`. I don't see why `img` needs to be a pointer, so the simple solution is to fix that. You still pass a pointer to that struct to `read_pgm()` but `read_pgm()` does not need to return a value.

```
int main(){
    struct image img;  // <- Not a pointer
    read_pgm("C:/MinGW/bin/image_P5.pgm", &img); // <- passing pointer to struct
    write_pgm("C:/MinGW/bin/write_P5.pgm", &img);
    .....
```

Comment: I did this and even after this, it is not working . Probably , more bugs in it ?

Comment: @John Yes, this only fixes the one error. **Enable all compiler warnings**. For example, I just noticed that `int **mem_alloc()` does not return anything. Your compiler should warn you of that.

Comment: I use MinGW and it is not saying anything ! It seemingly freezes for a few seconds and then it stops running the executable . Please help me how to fix the error that you found .

Comment: @John Just add `return q;` as the last line of `mem_alloc()`.

Comment: Now , I am getting an infinite loop if I try to print the matrix !

Comment: @John Where is it getting stuck and how do you know it is stuck?

Comment: I have fixed the code now .Thank you very much for your help . Code debugging does teach us a lot !